# WebSphere (wsadmin) Connect to remote Deployment Manager Profile password-less

Tags: soap, websphere, wsadmin

I'm able to connect to a remote WAS 8.5.5 deployment manager profile after supplying the user/pass from my local WAS 8.5 install. Given below is a typical wsadmin command...

```
./wsadmin.sh \
-lang jython \
-conntype SOAP -host myRemoteWASHost -port 12345 \
-user wasAdminUser -password wasPassword
```

**How can I connect to remote password less; using the UserId and (xor) Password already populated in the remote WAS Profile soap.client.props file?**

Answer (score 1):

Put that userid and password in to `soap.client.props` in the profile from where you start the `wsadmin` tool. You may need to create new dummy local profile to not clash with your local profile, if the profile from where you run the wsadmin has different username/password.